# How to animate a sequence of maps in postscript format?

Tags: maps, animation, postscript

I'm working on the Atlantic ocean for my research and I need to create an animation of movement of few islands in the Atlantic from their past locations to their present locations that moved due to plate tectonics. Input will be a postscript file of that region.

[image]

Are there any tools which can do this task?

Comment: There are many GIS programs that can create animations based on a Time attribute or multiple attributes.  Postscript files are not typically associated with GIS.  Can you tell us more about the postscript file?  How was it created? With what software?

Comment: The file was created from satellite altimeter data using Generic Mapping Tools(GMT). I can give jpeg file as output(if that helps)

Comment: Can you post an image of one of your outputs?  I'm thinking you could use the open source GIMP program to produce animations of your images.

Comment: @Fezter: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IP55t.jpg      This image show a region of the atlantic ocean...I need to move the small islands seen on the bottom to their past locations.

Answer (score 4):

My usual method is to use the `convert` utility from either [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) or [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html) to convert a sequence of still images from a variety of formats, including PostScript, and output a variety of other formats, such as an animated GIF or [MNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-image_Network_Graphics).

For example, from a directory with several PostScript files, make an animated GIF with 0.2 seconds between each frame:

```
$ convert -delay 20 map*.ps map.gif
```

ImageMagick's version [has many more options, such as `-layers method`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#layers), which can be used to control how a GIF animation is constructed. There are also plenty of options to control how the PostScript files are converted too. You may want to pre-process each PostScript still files into individual .png frames if this step is complicated.

Also, make sure your file names are sequenced correctly, like `map0001.ps`, `map0002.ps`, ..., `map0365.ps`, otherwise you might have odd jumps of frames.